# undefined method `linkedin' for #<User:0xaa6c9a8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise gem, gem 'koala', '~> 1.10.1', gem 'omniauth'

gem 'omniauth-facebook'

gem 'omniauth-twitter'

gem 'omniauth-linkedin'

gem 'linkedin'

It's not working for autopost comment to linkedin.

I have code in #user.rb

```
def linkedin_client
  client = LinkedIn::Client.new("API Key", "Secret Key")
  client.authorize_from_access(oauth_token, oauth_secret)
  client
end
```

Code in #reviews_controller.rb

```
if current_user.provider == "facebook"
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.oauth_token)
  @graph.put_wall_post(@review.body)
elsif current_user.provider == "linkedin"
  current_user.linkedin.add_share(:comment => @review.body)
end
redirect_to product_path(@product)
end
```

Please tell me where did i make a mistake. Help me.

Comment: undefined method `linkedin'

Comment: Yes I think that's the problem as @ryan said you are using 'current_user.linkedin', but there is no method as such use 'current_user.linkedin_client'

Comment: Yeah. But earlier i used 'linkedin_client'. But it's shows the erro **private method `linkedin_client' called for #<User:0xbbdc7b0>**. Thanks for your reply @Sontya.

Comment: I am currently not working on ruby but try in User moedel `self.linkedin_client` means a class method, and in controller say `User.linkedin_client.add_share(:comment => @review.body)`. Give a try I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Specify require linkedin in your code

```
require 'linkedin'
require 'json'
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The method you've defined is `linkedin_client`, but you're trying to refer to it as `linkedin`. Fix one or the other.